# How do I evaluate my functions over a range of values?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, core-language, iterators, index

I want to use the list of data which will come from `MapData1` (in code); the first element is θ and second is Action(I). I want to use this Action(I) and Angle(θ) in `χ1` which will provide $n$ values of `χ1`. Using this, I want to get values of `K1` which will also give $n$ values of `K1`. I want these values of `K1` so I can get values of `η[n]` and `η[n - 1]` and `ξ[n]` and `ξ[n - 1]` for various values of `n`.

```
Kx1 = 1.75; n = 100; θ1 = 0; θ2 = π / 2; rmax = 2 π; nr = 10;

fxy[θ_, r_] := 
  N[{Mod[θ + r - Kx1 Sin[θ], 2 π, -π], Mod[r - Kx1 Sin[θ], 2 π, -π]}];

MapData1 = 
  Flatten[
    Table[
      Join[
        NestList[fxy @@ # &, {θ1, i rmax / nr}, n], 
        NestList[fxy @@ # &, {θ2, i rmax / nr}, n]], 
      {i, 0, nr}], 
    1];

χ1 = -1/2 Sqrt[(2 MapData1[[All, 2]])/(.2)]Cos[MapData1[[All, 1]]];

ζ = -1/2 0.2 10;

K1 = Sin[ζ] Cot[χ1];

\[Phi]1[n_] := ArcCos[Cos[Cos[\[Chi]1[n]] Cos[\[Zeta]]]];

η[n_] =  1/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[Sqrt[1 + K1^2]] Sqrt[Sqrt[1 + K1^2] + K1]);

ξ[n_] = 
  (Sqrt[1 + K1^2] + K1) / 
    (Sqrt[2] Sqrt[Sqrt[1 + K1^2]] Sqrt[Sqrt[1 + K1^2] + K1]);

A11[n_] := Exp[-I \[Phi]1[ n]] ( \[Eta][n] \[Eta][n - 1] + \[Xi][n] \ 
           [Xi][n - 1]);
A12[n_] := Exp[-I \[Phi]1[ n]] ( \[Eta][n] \[Xi][n - 1] - \[Xi][n] \ 
           [Eta][n - 1]);
A21[n_] := Exp[I \[Phi]1[n]] (- \[Eta][n] \[Xi][n - 1] + \[Xi][n] \ 
           [Eta][n - 1]);
A22[n_] := Exp[I \[Phi]1[n]] ( \[Eta][n] \[Eta][n - 1] + \[Xi][n] \[Xi] 
           [n - 1]);
Matrix[n_] := {{A11[n], A12[n]}, {A21[n], A22[n]}};

bigN = 500;

matrices = Map[Matrix, Range[bigN]];

mat = Apply[Dot, matrices]
\[Sigma]z[n_] := 
 Abs[mat[[1, 1]]]^2 Abs[\[Eta][1]]^2 (Abs[\[Eta][bigN]]^2 - 
  Abs[\[Xi][bigN]]^2) + 
  mat[[1, 2]] Conjugate[
 mat[[1, 1]]] Abs[\[Eta][
   1]]^2 (\[Xi][bigN] Conjugate[\[Eta][bigN]] + \[Eta][
    bigN] Conjugate[\[Xi][bigN]]) + 
  mat[[2, 1]] Conjugate[mat[[1, 1]]] \[Xi][
 1] Conjugate[\[Eta][1]] Exp[
 2 I \[Phi]1[n]] (Abs[\[Eta][bigN]]^2 - Abs[\[Xi][bigN]]^2) + 
  mat[[2, 2]] Conjugate[mat[[1, 1]]] \[Xi][
 1] Conjugate[\[Eta][1]] Exp[
 2 I \[Phi]1[
   n]] (\[Xi][bigN] Conjugate[\[Eta][bigN]] + \[Eta][
    bigN] Conjugate[\[Xi][bigN]]) + 
  mat[[1, 1]] Conjugate[
  mat[[1, 2]]] Abs[\[Eta][
   1]]^2 (\[Xi][bigN] Conjugate[\[Eta][bigN]] + \[Eta][
    bigN] Conjugate[\[Xi][bigN]]) + 
  Abs[mat[[1, 2]]]^2 Abs[\[Eta][1]]^2 (-Abs[\[Eta][bigN]]^2 + 
  Abs[\[Xi][bigN]]^2) + 
  mat[[2, 1]] Conjugate[mat[[1, 2]]] \[Xi][
 1] Conjugate[\[Eta][1]] Exp[
 2 I \[Phi]1[
   n]] (\[Xi][bigN] Conjugate[\[Eta][bigN]] + \[Eta][
    bigN] Conjugate[\[Xi][bigN]]) + 
  mat[[2, 2]] Conjugate[mat[[1, 2]]] \[Xi][
 1] Conjugate[\[Eta][1]] Exp[
 2 I \[Phi]1[n]] (-Abs[\[Eta][bigN]]^2 + Abs[\[Xi][bigN]]^2) + 
 mat[[1, 1]] Conjugate[mat[[2, 1]]] \[Eta][
 1] Conjugate[\[Xi][
  1]] Exp[-2 I \[Phi]1[n]] (Abs[\[Eta][bigN]]^2 - 
  Abs[\[Xi][bigN]]^2) + 
 mat[[1, 2]] Conjugate[mat[[2, 1]]] \[Eta][
 1] Conjugate[\[Xi][
  1]] Exp[-2 I \[Phi]1[
   n]] (\[Xi][bigN] Conjugate[\[Eta][bigN]] + \[Eta][
    bigN] Conjugate[\[Xi][bigN]]) + 
 Abs[mat[[2, 1]]]^2 Abs[\[Xi][1]]^2 (Abs[\[Eta][bigN]]^2 - 
  Abs[\[Xi][bigN]]^2) + 
 mat[[2, 2]] Conjugate[
 mat[[2, 1]]] Abs[\[Xi][
   1]]^2 (\[Xi][bigN] Conjugate[\[Eta][bigN]] + \[Eta][
    bigN] Conjugate[\[Xi][bigN]]) + 
  mat[[1, 1]] Conjugate[mat[[2, 2]]] \[Eta][
 1] Conjugate[\[Xi][
  1]] Exp[-2 I \[Phi]1[
   n]] (\[Xi][bigN] Conjugate[\[Eta][bigN]] + \[Eta][
    bigN] Conjugate[\[Xi][bigN]]) + 
 mat[[1, 2]] Conjugate[mat[[2, 2]]] \[Eta][
 1] Conjugate[\[Xi][
  1]] Exp[-2 I \[Phi]1[n]] (-Abs[\[Eta][bigN]]^2 + 
  Abs[\[Xi][bigN]]^2) + 
 mat[[2, 1]] Conjugate[
 mat[[2, 2]]] Abs[\[Xi][
   1]]^2 (\[Xi][bigN] Conjugate[\[Eta][bigN]] + \[Eta][
    bigN] Conjugate[\[Xi][bigN]]) + 
 Abs[mat[[2, 2]]]^2 Abs[\[Xi][1]]^2 (-Abs[\[Eta][bigN]]^2 + 
  Abs[\[Xi][bigN]]^2);

\[Sigma]x[n_] := 
 Abs[mat[[1, 1]]]^2 Abs[\[Eta][
   1]]^2 (\[Xi][bigN] Conjugate[\[Eta][bigN]] + \[Eta][
    bigN] Conjugate[\[Xi][bigN]]) + 
 mat[[1, 2]] Conjugate[
 mat[[1, 1]]] Abs[\[Eta][1]]^2 (-Abs[\[Eta][bigN]]^2 + 
  Abs[\[Xi][bigN]]^2) + 
 mat[[2, 1]] Conjugate[mat[[1, 1]]] \[Xi][
 1] Conjugate[\[Eta][1]] Exp[
 2 I \[Phi]1[
   n]] (\[Xi][bigN] Conjugate[\[Eta][bigN]] + \[Eta][
    bigN] Conjugate[\[Xi][bigN]]) + 
 mat[[2, 2]] Conjugate[mat[[1, 1]]] \[Xi][
 1] Conjugate[\[Eta][1]] Exp[
 2 I \[Phi]1[n]] (-Abs[\[Eta][bigN]]^2 + Abs[\[Xi][bigN]]^2) + 
 mat[[1, 1]] Conjugate[
 mat[[1, 2]]] Abs[\[Eta][1]]^2 (-Abs[\[Eta][bigN]]^2 + 
  Abs[\[Xi][bigN]]^2) + 
 Abs[mat[[1, 2]]]^2 Abs[\[Eta][
   1]]^2 (-\[Xi][bigN] Conjugate[\[Eta][bigN]] - \[Eta][
    bigN] Conjugate[\[Xi][bigN]]) + 
 mat[[2, 1]] Conjugate[mat[[1, 2]]] \[Xi][
 1] Conjugate[\[Eta][1]] Exp[
 2 I \[Phi]1[n]] (-Abs[\[Eta][bigN]]^2 + Abs[\[Xi][bigN]]^2) + 
 mat[[2, 2]] Conjugate[mat[[1, 2]]] \[Xi][
 1] Conjugate[\[Eta][1]] Exp[
 2 I \[Phi]1[
   n]] (-\[Xi][bigN] Conjugate[\[Eta][bigN]] - \[Eta][
    bigN] Conjugate[\[Xi][bigN]]) +
 mat[[1, 1]] Conjugate[mat[[2, 1]]] \[Eta][
 1] Conjugate[\[Xi][
  1]] Exp[-2 I \[Phi]1[
   n]] (\[Xi][bigN] Conjugate[\[Eta][bigN]] + \[Eta][
    bigN] Conjugate[\[Xi][bigN]]) + 
 mat[[1, 2]] Conjugate[mat[[2, 1]]] \[Eta][
 1] Conjugate[\[Xi][
  1]] Exp[-2 I \[Phi]1[n]] (-Abs[\[Eta][bigN]]^2 + 
  Abs[\[Xi][bigN]]^2) + 
 Abs[mat[[2, 1]]]^2 Abs[\[Xi][
   1]]^2 (\[Xi][bigN] Conjugate[\[Eta][bigN]] + \[Eta][
    bigN] Conjugate[\[Xi][bigN]]) + 
 mat[[2, 2]] Conjugate[
 mat[[2, 1]]] Abs[\[Xi][1]]^2 (-Abs[\[Eta][bigN]]^2 + 
  Abs[\[Xi][bigN]]^2) +
 mat[[1, 1]] Conjugate[mat[[2, 2]]] \[Eta][
 1] Conjugate[\[Xi][
  1]] Exp[-2 I \[Phi]1[n]] (-Abs[\[Eta][bigN]]^2 + 
  Abs[\[Xi][bigN]]^2) + 
mat[[1, 2]] Conjugate[mat[[2, 2]]] \[Eta][
 1] Conjugate[\[Xi][
  1]] Exp[-2 I \[Phi]1[
   n]] (-\[Xi][bigN] Conjugate[\[Eta][bigN]] - \[Eta][
    bigN] Conjugate[\[Xi][bigN]]) + 
 mat[[2, 1]] Conjugate[
 mat[[2, 2]]] Abs[\[Xi][1]]^2 (-Abs[\[Eta][bigN]]^2 + 
  Abs[\[Xi][bigN]]^2) + 
 Abs[mat[[2, 2]]]^2 Abs[\[Xi][
   1]]^2 (-\[Xi][bigN] Conjugate[\[Eta][bigN]] - \[Eta][
    bigN] Conjugate[\[Xi][bigN]]);
 f2 = ListPlot[MapData, PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[0.0001]}, 
  PlotRange -> \[Pi] {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Frame -> True, 
  RotateLabel -> False, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 16, Thickness[0.0025]], 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "Times" , Black}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"\[Theta]", "I", "", ""}, Axes -> False]
```

Similarly, I want to plot the Poincare section between [Sigmax] and [Sigmaz] as I plotted between I(action) and [Theta] in f2 in the code.

Comment: If I understand your code correctly you will end up with n values of Eta and Xi at least from the right hand side of the last two lines. All you then need to do is to use 'Part[]' or [[n]] to choose the value you want.

Comment: yes, you understand it right. It does not work.

Answer (score 3):

This is only a partial answer, but it is the best I do without knowing the mathematical or physical context of your problem,

Your code needs to completely refactored to produce `χ1` as vector, but even then the values that appear in `k1`, which is derived from `χ1`, make me think there are also errors in the formation of the mathematics that your code is trying to implement.

In order to work with data of a reasonable size during debugging, I change your parameters `n` and `nr` to

```
n = 5; nr = 3;
```

The other parameters remain the same.

```
θ1 = 0.; θ2 = N @ π/2; rmax = N[2 π]; ζ = -1/2 2/10 10 // N
```

Since we will apply `fxy` to ***coordinate pairs***, it make more sense to define it by

```
With[{Kx1 = 1.75},
  fxy[{θ_, r_}] := {Mod[θ + r - Kx1 Sin[θ], 2 π, -π], Mod[r - Kx1 Sin[θ], 2 π, -π]}]
```

With this definition, you can get vectors of the x-coordinates and y-coordinates with

```
{datax, datay} =
  Transpose[
    Catenate[
      Table[
        Join[
          NestList[fxy, {θ1, i rmax/nr}, n],
          NestList[fxy, {θ2, i rmax/nr}, n]],
        {i, 0, nr}]]];
```

and your vector `χ1` with

```
χ1 = MapThread[-1/2 Sqrt[(10 #2)] Cos[#1] &, {datax, datay}];
```

Now we would seem to be home and safe, but are we?

```
k1 = Quiet[Sin[ζ] Cot[χ1]]
```

> ```
> {ComplexInfinity, ComplexInfinity, ComplexInfinity, ComplexInfinity, ComplexInfinity, 
> ComplexInfinity, ComplexInfinity, 0. - 0.869365 I, 0. + 9.57682 I, 3.60415, -0.127353, 
> -140.065, -0.734212, -0.382542, -0.456829, 0. + 1.64418 I,  0. - 1.34105 I, 
> 0. + 1.81719 I, 6.00564*10^15, -2.59753, 0. - 0.934063 I, 0. + 2.88027 I, 
> 0. + 1.30193 I, 8.65149, 8.88261, 0. + 1.03147 I, 0. + 1.06415 I, -1.32694, 0.926691, 
> -1.53591, 4.24663*10^15, 0.021206, 0. - 4.83268 I, 0.47543, -1.36006, 0.984522, 
> 0.782438, ComplexInfinity, ComplexInfinity, ComplexInfinity, ComplexInfinity, 
> ComplexInfinity, 3.46736*10^15, 0. - 0.869365 I, 0. + 9.57682 I, 3.60415, -0.127353, 
> -140.065}
> ```

This result does not look good to me. I don't like the `ComplexInfinity` entries nor the extreme range in the real values. I am also suspicious of the complex values. However, only you know, from the context of your problem, whether or not these kind of elements should be appearing in `k1`.

Finally, assuming that we had a valid `ki` vector`,`η`  and  ξ can be written as

```
η[n_] :=
  With[{k = k1[[n]]}, 1/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[Sqrt[1 + k^2]] Sqrt[Sqrt[1 + k^2] + k])]

ξ[n_] :=
  With[{k = k1[[n]]},
    (Sqrt[1 + k^2] + k)/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[Sqrt[1 + k^2]] Sqrt[Sqrt[1 + k^2] + k])]
```

I hope this helps you proceed in the debugging of your code.

Comment: Sir, Thanks for the reply  I want to use this \Eta[n]   and \Xi[n]   for plot Poincare section as I plotted for I(action) and \Theta (angle).                                                                                               'f2 = ListPlot[MapData1, PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[0.0001]}, 
  PlotRange -> \[Pi] {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Frame -> True, 
  RotateLabel -> False, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 16, Thickness[0.0025]], 
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "Times" , Black}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"\[Theta]", "I", "", ""}, Axes -> False]'

Comment: I want to plot the Poincare section between \Sigmax and \Sigmaz Code I have written as follows  "\[Phi]1 = Quiet[ArcCos[Cos[Cos[\[Chi]1] Cos[\[Zeta]]]]]"

Comment: @user68207. I am sorry but what is in my answer is all I have to say about your problem. The additional requests for help that you make in the above comments should made by either editing your question or put into a new question, perhaps referencing this one.

Comment: Dear Sir, Thanks for the reply I will edit my question so that you may help me.

Comment: Dear Sir,  I have edited the code, please see it maybe you can help me now.  remove some values from the set of data which are giving complexInfinity that is from \[Xi] the values coming from  0 and \Pi.